# LibGdx - Place Actor outside stage

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

For some reason I can't find an answer for this.

I want to place my actor outside the Screen (or Stage) and then add an Action to move it into the Screen.

I've tried:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setX(-100) //place outside of screen

Label label = new Label("test", skin);
table.add(label);

table.addAction(Actions.moveBy(200f, 0f, 1f)); //move into Screen

//...

anotherTable.add(table); //I've tried setting X here aswell but to no effect
```

Whatever I do the table just starts in the middle of the Screen and then starts moving, even if I add a position that's inside the Screen like (100, 100), it still just places itself in the middle. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling `table.setFillParent(true);` somewhere in your code because that would make the table have a fixed position and would disable the ability to change it (which makes sense, if you think of `setFillParent`'s point).

Obviously you can fix this by removing `table.setFillParent(true);`. If you need that functionality, you can call that line once you are done moving the table to its position.

Comment: Ah, so there is not other way, was afraid of that. Thanks for the answer!